# Convergence of Improper Integrals

Tags: calculus, intuition, improper-integrals

I  am working on some exercises for Improper Integrals (not homework). The question is 1.c in Folland Advanced Calculus :

$$\int_0^\infty x^2 e^{-x^2 } \, dx$$

It asks whether the above Improper Integral is convergent. Folland's answer to this is that it is convergent. I however cant see how that could be. If I use the theorem (4.55 in text) that states:

> $$0\le f\left( x \right) \le g(x) \text{ for all sufficiently large }x. \\\text{If }\int_0^\infty g(x) \, dx \text{ converges so does }\int_0^\infty f(x) \, dx.$$

then I just can't think of a $g(x)$ that would satisfy this.

Comment: Have you thought about using any other methods than this one theorem?

Comment: I've edited your question to use $\LaTeX$.  Please make sure it still represents your original intent.

Comment: @L.F is e^x larger than x^2 ?

Comment: @KjTada For large $x$, yes! In fact, here's a better suggestion: $g(x)=e^{-x^2/2}$ (replacing $x^2$ with $e^{x^2/2}$; the inequality is true over the entire real line)

Comment: @anoton : You $\LaTeX$ was full of things like {{x}^{2}} where x^2 suffices.  It can be hard to edit code when you clutter it that way, and it sets a bad example for people who learn $\LaTeX$ by looking at things like this.

Comment: I have two corollaries at my disposal as well.. (4.56 and 4.57 in text) one where I need to find a $$g(x)\quad s.t\quad f(x)/g(x)\longrightarrow l\\ and\quad the\quad other\quad where\quad I\quad can\quad find\quad a\quad C{ x }^{ -p }\quad $$ larger than f(x).

Comment: I see: The original poster did it that way.  I'm sorry "anorton".

Comment: @L.F Thankyou I had graphed e^x but didnt know that it was larger than x^2 for a very large x. Thankyou everyone.

Comment: @KjTada For the record, any exponential with base $>1$ exceeds any polynomial for $x$ sufficiently large. So even $1.00001^x$ will eventually get larger than $x^{100000}$. For the integral, the second example I gave is perhaps more explicit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $g(x) = e^{-x} $.Than  $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$. So there is $K$ that $g(x)\geq f(x)$ for $x\in (K,\infty)$.

$\int_K^\infty e^{-x} = e^{-K} < \infty$.

Therefore $\int _{ K }^{ \infty  }{ { x }^{ 2 } } { e }^{ { -x }^{ 2 } }dx < \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} x^2 e^{-x^2} \, dx < \int_0^\infty e^{-x^2+x} \, dx = e^{1/4}\int_0^\infty e^{-(x-1/2)^2}\,dx  < \infty. $$